# To see that the fundamental class of a local complete intersection is independent of choice of regular sequence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, etale-cohomology, cup-product

In SGA 4½ ‘Cycle,’ Grothendieck defines (among other things) the fundamental class of a local complete intersection $Y\subset X$ ($X$ simply a noetherian scheme) of codimension $c$ locally as the cup-product of the fundamental classes of each divisor $D_i$ in a regular sequence. To argue that this cup-product does not depend on the choice of the regular sequence, he claims that the product only depends on the ‘flag’ $D_1\supset D_1\cap D_2\supset\ldots\supset Y$. To show this, he asserts the existence of a cup-product
$$H^*_{D_1}(X)\otimes H^*_{D_1\cap D_2}(D_1)\otimes\ldots\otimes H_Y^*(D_1\cap\ldots\cap D_{c-1})\longrightarrow H^*_Y(X).\tag{*}$$
To try to see the existence of such a product, first I begin to consider a product (for sheaves $\mathcal F,\mathcal G$ on $X$; we can take $\mathcal F=\mathcal G=\mathbf{Z}/n(1)=\mu_n$)
$$\Gamma_{D_1}(X,\mathcal F)\otimes\Gamma_{D_1\cap D_2}(D_1,\mathcal G)\longrightarrow\Gamma_{D_1\cap D_2}(X,\mathcal F\otimes\mathcal G).$$
This is fine: take a global section $s$ of $\mathcal F$ with support in $D_1$ and any section $t$ representing a global section of $\mathcal G$ restricted to $D_1$ so that the restriction of $t$ to $D_1$ has support in $D_1\cap D_2$; then the tensor product $s\otimes t$ does not depend on the choice of $t$ and indeed has support in $D_1\cap D_2$. My problem is when I try to derive this arrow to give a map
$$R\Gamma_{D_1}(X,\mathcal F)\otimes^L R\Gamma_{D_1\cap D_2}(D_1,\mathcal G)\longrightarrow R\Gamma_{D_1\cap D_2}(X,\mathcal F\otimes^L\mathcal G).$$
The matter of finding complexes adapted to both $\Gamma$ and $\otimes$ is not the issue: it’s the $R\Gamma_{D_1\cap D_2}(D_1,\mathcal G)$ term. To compute this I need to find an injective resolution $\mathcal I^\bullet$ of the restriction of $\mathcal G$ to $D_1$. But then $\mathcal I^\bullet$ is just a complex of sheaves on $D_1$ not given as the restriction of a complex on $X$, and so I can’t follow the recipe outlined above. How to see the product (*)? Thank you.